# Python 3.6 Tensor Flow: Cannot import name 'nccl_ops'

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.6, nvidia

I am trying to test NVIDIA's [Style GAN](https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan/) and am encountering an error when trying to run the [pretrained_example.py](https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan/blob/master/pretrained_example.py) file.

I get an import error from the line `from tensorflow.python.ops import nccl_ops`

> ImportError: cannot import name 'nccl_ops'

I think I installed all the prerequisites properly and am using python 3.6. It could be a mac tensorflow issue possibly because it doesn't mention OSX on the github project. Any help would be appreciated. It might be a matter of installing a different version of tensorflow or something else, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated tensorflow and it solved this issue